# Changing home controller on web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, visual-studio-2019

I created a small web api project. 
Edit: When I create a new WEBAPI project in Visual Studio 2019, these are the options available. I cannot uncheck "MVC" in the checkbox.

[image]

I deleted the home controller. Now I intended to point the default web page to the Help controller, so I made this change to the `RouteConfig.cs` file. Now my code in the `RegisterRoute` function reads.

**Edit: I received a close vote on my question. Not sure why. So I am adding the entire RegisterRoute function from my project. Please note this is the default project template and the problem is easily reproducible if you have a VS2019 IDE at your disposal.**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();



    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**RegisterRoute in RouteConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
}
```

Still I keep getting a Resource Not found page when I run this project. All of the methods, I am testing from Postman are working.

Comment: You have MapHttpAttributeRoutes but you aren't showing us your attribute route implementation. Please review the criteria for [MCVE].

Comment: I started off with a brand new project in VS 2019. I have listed the steps to get to the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Help",
url: "{controller}/{action}",
defaults: new { controller = "Help", action = "Index" }
);
```

When you are mentioning the default action method, there is not need to give the controller name with action method. Just give the name of the method which you want as default.

Comment: I believe if you create a default project using VS 2019, you'll land into the same problem as me. The only code I have modified is the RouteCOnfig.cs and WebApiconfig.cs (Both posted above).